# Postgres query to fetch records from table having a column of type Array of Objects

Tags: postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have a table having two properties called `id` and `categoryArray` where `id` is of type `number` and `categoryArray` is a `jsonb[]` column and schema is as mentioned below:

```
"id": 1,
"categoryArray": [{
            "Field1": "A",
            "Field2": "A1"
        },
        {
            "Field1": "B",
            "Field2": "A2"
        },
        {
            "Field1": "C",
            "Field2": "A3"
        }
    ]
```

The table will have multiple record with disctint `id`s and will have objects inside `categoryArray`.

I want to query in PostgreSQL all the `id`s where `Field1 = A` inside `categoryArray` object.

I have tried using `jsonb_array_elements` but not able to achieve expected result.

Do we have a possible way to query on basis of `Field1` which is inside `categoryArray` object.

Comment: categoryArray is `jsonb` or `jsonb[]`?..

Comment: categoryArray is a jsonb[].

Comment: they use `unnest`... `jsonb[]` is a very unpopular choice... for a reason

Comment: `jsonb[]` makes no sense whatsoever. It's much more efficient to store a "native" JSON array inside a `jsonb` column. `jsonb_array_elements` only works with an array _inside_ a JSON, not with an array of JSON values

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using `jsonb[]`, you can use following query to get records having value of `Field1 = A` using subscript generating function, `generate_subscripts()`.

```sql
select 
   * 
from 
   table 
where 
   id in 
   (
      select 
         id 
      from 
      (
         select 
            id,
            categoryArray, 
            generate_subscripts(categoryArray, 1) as s 
         FROM 
            table 
      ) as i
      where 
         categoryArray[s]->>'Field1' = 'A'
   );
```